# setting and getting time from Date in java

Tags: java, date, java-7

I have a `Date` . I want to copy its time only, excluding the date. I then need to insert the time into another date.

Is there a easy way to do this?. I cant change the Date datatype. I can do, getHour(),getMinutes() etc however this is long winded. is there a clearner version that i could use ? or perhaps other library's like apache commons to set/get date time (have not spotten anything so far).

Comment: Use Java 8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: unable to use java 8

Comment: there is no short way to do that with the standard java library. You have to set hour, then minutes, then seconds... Have a look at [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html) it may suits your needs

Comment: By inserting into another Date, do you mean adding, removing, or simply creating a Date with just the time?

Comment: Null out year, month,day fields of your Date instance. essentially what you have is a time. Haven't managed to find easier ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Date copyTimeOnly(Date toDate, Date fromDate) {
    Calendar toCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    toCal.setTime(toDate);

    Calendar fromCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    fromCal.setTime(fromDate);

    // Copy time only
    toCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, fromCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    toCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, fromCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    toCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, fromCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    toCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, fromCal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    return toCal.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the time part of your `Date` object and you can't use Java 8 and don't want to use any third party framework, then use [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
c.set(Calendar.DAY, 0);
Date timeOnly = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you can use third party libraries(in this case `org.apache.commons.lang3.time`)
you could do it this way:

```
private Date truncate(Date pDate) {
    return DateUtils.truncate(pDate, Calendar.DATE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## `LocalTime`

The old java.util.Date/.Calendar have no class to represent a time-of-day value without a date portion. In contrast, both the Joda-Time library and the new java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time) offer a `LocalTime` class.

## Joda-Time

Here is example code using Joda-Time 2.5.

Time zone is crucial. Do you want the time of day for that moment as seen by someone in Paris, Montréal, or Kolkata?

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( yourJUDate, zone );
LocalTime localTime = dateTime.toLocalTime();
```

To apply that LocalTime to another DateTime, call `withTime`. Joda-Time uses immutable objects. So a new DateTime object is created with values based on the original.